# moving grub to sda4, grub is on sda2, gparted shows swap/sda3 as boot - first move?

Tags: grub2

As stated in subject I want move grub to sda4 ext3, grub is on sda2 ext4 (a linux i don't want to use), gparted shows swap/sda3 as boot partition. What should be my first move?

First why is the swap showing as the boot partition?

I'm trying to install a new linux on sda3 partition and so that partition has been set to be the grub master. (found out when trying to update grub to boot from an iso on the drive so I can install a new linux.)

How do I change the boot partition to sda4? Can I just ignore the boot flag on the swap drive?

Comment: Usually you can ignore the boot flag. Linux nor Grub cares about that. But your question(s) is rather unclear. When you say you want to move grub to sda4 ext3, are you taking about moving the /boot partition or do you actually mean installing Grub into the partition rather than the MBR?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response - over the last 10 days I've learned a bit.

I found out that the boot flag is for windows. I was afraid Linux cared too. Now it is just a reminder that the computer came with Vista - which explains why the flag is on the swap partition - that seemed the best use for that waste of space.

I was asking how to move grub because when I edited the grub files on Ubuntu nothing changed. The active grub files were on the partition I wanted to put mint linux on and was afraid of loss of boot.

I found out my DVD drive was bad - replaced it and installed mint 17.1 - a new grub was installed there. I now understand that grub actually resides in the MBR. Since the install made a new grub and I can boot I don't need to know how to move where the grub menu comes from anymore.

On a side note, Linux mint won't install my Brother network printer.

Should I mark this solved when I didn't get an answer or is there another flag such as withdrawn?